# Lattice vs Level with regard to access control

Tags: access-control, mandatory-access-control

With regard to access control, is "lattice" the same as "level"? Is "Multi-level access control" just another name of "lattice-based access control"?

Are Biba and Bell-LaPadula Security Models examples of Lattice-based Access Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biba and Bell-LaPadula are generic models. One parameter of those generic models is a multi-level security policy.

A **multi-level security policy** is a pair (DOMS,≤) where (DOMS,≤) is a partially ordered set and DOMS is a set of security domains (this is what you refer to as level).

A **lattice** is a quadruple (L,≤,⊓,⊔) where (L,≤) is a partially ordered set, ⊓ is a least-upper-bound operator on (L,≤), and ⊔ is a greatest-lower-bound operator on (L,≤).

Not every multi-level security policy is a lattice, but there exist multi-level security policies that are lattices.

One could instantiate the Biba and Bell-LaPadula models with a multi-level security policy that is a lattice, but one does not need to.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context. Lattice is the join point of an security label, an object and a subject. At the end of the day, it's all about levels of "*who* can access *what* through *where*". It depends on what meaning you want to extract from the text you are reading, could be the same.

Those models(Biba an Bell-LaPadula) could be examples of Lacttice-based control, however, with different focuses. While Biba cares only with integrity(i cant mess with data that is not on my level of access), Bell-LaPadula cares about access(a given subject can't have access to objects or subjects that have higher label privileges than the one the subject have).